# Finding the calling (or parent) target in Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant

We use Ant to control our product creation workflow and the number of targets is quite extensive. We make use of numerous build.xml files, targets that call other targets (many of the targets running in parallel).

We have a java class that extends the Ant BuildListener so that we can listen for BuildEvents and write start and stop times for every target to an Oracle database. However, now I need to be able to figure out each target's parent target - this information needs to be logged as well. So if I have this:

```
<target name="targetA">
    <parallel>
        <antcall target="targetB"/>
        <antcall target="targetC"/>
    </parallel>
    <antcall target="targetD"/>
```

Sometimes our targets make several antcalls to targets in the same build.xml, and sometimes we make ant calls to other build.xmls in sub-directories specifying a target.

In any regard, I would like to know a way I can figure out that targetA is the parent of targetB. I thought I could have determined this information from the properties in the BuildEvent in my listener. But that does not seem to be available. So when I receive a BuildEvent telling me that targetB started, it appears that the BuildEvent doesn't know about TargetA.

Has anyone else tried something like this with success? I've been trying to use the listener, but would not oppose a post process that can determine the target hierarchy.

Comment: Are you building something, or are you using Ant as a programming language?

Comment: We're using ant to build our software and also as a workflow to build something (our product) - it's an ETL process. But some of the java classes within the software extend ant classes, like the BuildListener.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about this, but I guess that you could something like this (it assumes that when targets are run in parallel, they are run in a different thread than the main thread used by ant and that the other targets are run in the same thread as the one of the build listener):

```
import java.util.Stack;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Target;


public abstract class MyBuildListener implements BuildListener {

    private Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

    private Stack<Target> callingTargets = new Stack<Target>();

    private ThreadLocal<Stack<Target>> callingTargetsPerThread = new ThreadLocal<Stack<Target>>();

    @Override
    public void targetStarted(BuildEvent event) {
        if(Thread.currentThread()==mainThread) {
            printCallingStack(callingTargets);
            callingTargets.push(event.getTarget());
        } else {
            Stack<Target> callingTargetsForThread = callingTargetsPerThread.get();
            if(callingTargetsForThread==null) {
                callingTargetsPerThread.set(callingTargetsForThread = new Stack<Target>());
            }
            printCallingStack(callingTargetsForThread);
            printCallingStack(callingTargets);
            callingTargetsForThread.add(event.getTarget());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event) {
        if(Thread.currentThread()==mainThread) {
            callingTargets.pop();
        } else {
            Stack<Target> callingTargetsForThread = callingTargetsPerThread.get();
            callingTargetsForThread.pop();
            if (callingTargetsForThread.isEmpty()) {
                callingTargetsPerThread.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void printCallingStack(Stack<Target> stack) {
        for(int i=stack.size();i>=0;i--) {
            System.out.println(stack.get(i).getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure about your assumptions, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @JoeRoberts As far as I could read Ant code, my assumptions are acceptable. If you instantiate the BuildListener in the same thread as you run Ant, I believe my assumptions are correct. Running this in debug mode should quickly tell you if this is correct or not. You could also print out the name of the current thread in the constructor and the event-notification methods.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the right track. But it works until you encounter nested parallelism – which I have. Given this type of scenario:
<target name=”targetA”>
  <parallel>
  <ant dir=”dirB” antfile=”fileB” target=”targetB”>
  <ant dir=”dirC” antfile=”fileC” target=”targetC”>
 </parallel>
</target>
dirB/fileB:
<target name=”targetB”>
<parallel>
<antcall target=”targetX”>
<antcall target=”targetY”>
</parallel>
</target>
... targetB, targetX and targetY are invoked in three separate threads: I get a new stack with each targetStarted. I can’t really tell that targetB is a parent of either.

Comment: @JoeRoberts please edit the original question or post another one, because I can't read nor understand your last comment.

Comment: Sorry,  the comment didn’t get formatted as I had hoped. I said that this solution works until you encounter nested parallelism – which I have. I tried to layout an XML scenario where targetA calls targetB and targetC in parallel. TargetB then also calls targetX and targetY in parallel. When this happens, targetB, targetX and targetY are invoked in three separate threads: I get a new stack with each targetStarted BuildEvent. I can’t really tell that targetB is a parent of either targetX or targetY.

Comment: @JoeRoberts This approach won't work with recursive nesting. When the parallel task gets executed, it creates a single ThreadGroup containing all the "sub-threads" but this is unfortunately not enough to find back which Thread (and therefore which Target) initiated that group (you could find the list fo "possible" threads using ThreadGroup.getParent(), but that won't help you in your case